# Is it possible to create star pattern or star pyramid using switch case.?

Tags: php, switch-statement, ascii-art

I was wondering to know is it possible to create star pyramid using switch case.

Comment: Short answer: probably. Do you have any attempt to share with us?

Comment: <?php
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++){
echo “*&nbsp;”;
}
echo “<br>”;
}
?>

Comment: You keep failing to tag the language you are using on your questions. Stack Overflow is not just for PHP. Please tag your questions properly. Read and study [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) carefully. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use any loop or recursion, i think this is a solution for your query.

```
<?php
function star($star){
switch($star){
    case '1':
        return '*&nbsp;';
        break;

    case '2':
        return '*&nbsp;*&nbsp;';
        break;

    case '3':
        return '*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;';
        break;

    case '4':
        return '*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;';
        break;

    case '5':
        return '*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;*&nbsp;';
        break;

    default :
    break;
}
}
echo star('1')."<br>".star('2')."<br>".star('3')."<br>".star('4')."<br>".star('5');
```

?>

Comment: Thanks buddy. working exactly that  i want